MAUI MVVM ContentView used in multiple places in the project with multiple view models instead of just one
I am currently developing a .NET 8 MAUI targeted only on Windows platform, specifically, Target Windows Framework is 10.0.19041.0.
This .NET 8 MAUI project is contained within a larger .net solution. I am using MVVM pattern, and in the .NET 8 MAUI project I have a ContentView with its ViewModel. Lets call them InfoView (which is the VIEW) and InfoViewModel (ViewModel).
This InfoView(ContentView xaml) is used in multiple places in my UI, meaning is called from other ContentPages and such. The problem is that for each place the InfoView (ContentView) is called from another ContentPage, it creates a new instance of the view model and I only want a SINGULAR instance, because that viewmodel instance is hooked to several events, and if there are multiple instances of the view model, all those events will trigger for each instance which will decrease the app's performance.
Here is the MauiProgram.cs:
...
builder.Services.AddSingleton<InfoView>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<InfoViewModel>();
...

Here is the InfoView code behind:
public partial class InfoView: ContentView
{
    private InfoViewModel viewModel;

    public InfoView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // This could not be the best way to do this but here it is
        viewModel = (SequenceInfoViewModel)BindingContext;
    }

    ...
}

Viewmodel code:
public partial class InfoViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    // ... members and properties
    public InfoViewModel()
    {
        // ... other initializations and event hooks
    }


}

And here is how I call the InfoView (ContentView page) from other locations in xaml:
<ContentPage ...>
    <Border Grid.Row="1"
            StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10"
            Margin="4,4,2,2"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Border.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush Center="1.3, 0.7">
                <GradientStop Color="{Binding FlashingStatusColor}"
                              Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="DimGray"
                              Offset="1" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <!--> Here is where I use the existing content view<-->
        <local:InfoView Padding="12, 0"/>
    </Border>
</ContentPage>

I have tried to dependency inject the view model in the code behind but then I have an error stating that the InfoView (ContentView) is missing an empty constructor.
I appreciate any input, thank you!

ContentViews typically shouldn't have their own ViewModel, the BindingContext is usually inherited from the parent Page. You can use bindable properties and pass everything through that to the ContentView or bind the BindingContext to an instance of the ViewModel which would have to be a child of the page's ViewModel. Otherwise, if you need dependency injection, you don't have any other choice than using the service locator (anti) pattern in the code-behind of your ContentView.

Does this answer your question? Create Child View using .NET DI container .NET MAUI or Dependency Injection when nesting Views in MAUI

I've seen this answer a bit too late. If you make a new question, I can show you how to manage your content views, without "service locator".

A ContentView shouldn’t have it’s own ViewModel. Instead it should take the one of its Parent, Which it does by default. So removing your viewmodel code entirely and using DI in your ContantPages to set the BindingContext should do the job.
Secondly in your current code you are not setting BindingContext to your ViewModel in the ContentView

This is true, but in my context, the content view has a collectionview that has to be dynamically updated, and should be the same everywhere the content view is present, that is why I need a viewmodel for the content view.

@GeluPopa that is still fine. You can use BindableProperties to assign your Property for colllection view from your parent itself.
